# How to create a MariaDB 10 "VIEW" using LEFT OUTER JOIN excluding duplicate results

Tags: join, view, mariadb, outer-join

What changes to this database query are needed to create a VIEW while excluding the duplicate results?

```
SELECT 

`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity`.`online_store_product_reference` , 
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity`.`quantity` AS inventory_quantity , 
`acts2301_money`.`paypal_cart_info`.`quantity` AS purchase_quantity_cart ,
`acts2301_money`.`paypal_payment_info`.`quantity` AS purchase_quantity_payment ,
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product`.`low_inventory_alert_quantity` , 
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product`.`live` , 
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product`.`discontinued`

FROM ( ( 
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
`acts2301_money`.`paypal_cart_info` 
ON `acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity`.`online_store_product_reference` = `acts2301_money`.`paypal_cart_info`.`itemnumber` ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
`acts2301_money`.`paypal_payment_info` 
ON `acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity`.`online_store_product_reference` = `acts2301_money`.`paypal_payment_info`.`itemnumber` )
INNER JOIN
`acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product`
ON `acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product_quantity`.`online_store_product_reference` = `acts2301_online_store`.`online_store_product`.`reference`
```

Comment: Neither query removed the duplicates.  Would it be helpful for me to post the database structure with some records?

Comment: This is what the current results are:  online_store_product_reference  inventory_quantity  purchase_quantity_cart  purchase_quantity_payment  low_inventory_alert_quantity  live  discontinued  
23  23  1  NULL 5  1  0
23  4  1  NULL 5  1  0
23  23  4  NULL 5  1  0
23  4  4  NULL 5  1  0